# Documentations list in user's profile

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, profile-page

Just like user's posts (asked questions and answers) appear in its profile, should not there be list of documentations authored by user?

Comment: There's a [documentation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1571115/titan?tab=documentation) in your profile now. Does that address what you're looking for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=documentation

Comment: There are some things missing, but what's available is there.

Comment: thanks @JoshCaswell for your comments too. Perhaps you are right.